# Updating State Object React

Tags: reactjs

How would I update the stock number of a car with a given index using an increment function? I'm assuming I need to use setState but I'm not sure how to implement that. If I use setState inside the increment function will my react component re-render?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cars: [
                {
                    "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                    "model": "Rav4",
                    "year": 2008,
                    "stock": 3,
                    "price": 8500
                },
    
                {
                    "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                    "model": "Camry",
                    "year": 2009,
                    "stock": 2,
                    "price": 6500
                },
    ]
        };
    }

    increment(index)
    {
        //Need to increment the stock number by 1 here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
            <tr>
              <th>manufacturer</th>
              <th>model</th>
              <th>year</th>
              <th>stock</th>
              <th>price</th>
              <th>option</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{this.state.cars[0].manufacturer}</td>
                <td>{this.state.cars[0].model}</td>
                <td>{this.state.cars[0].year}</td>
                <td>{this.state.cars[0].stock}</td>
                <td>${this.state.cars[0].price}.00</td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.increment(0)}>Increment</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button>Decrement</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{this.state.cars[1].manufacturer}|</td>
                <td>{this.state.cars[1].model}</td>
                <td>{this.state.cars[1].year}</td>
                <td>{this.state.cars[1].stock}</td>
                <td>${this.state.cars[1].price}.00</td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.increment(1)}>Increment</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button>Decrement</button>
                </td>
            </tr>`your text`
          </table>
        );
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

I'm assuming I need to use setState in my increment function but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be re-rendered.

```
const newCar = this.state.car;
newCar[index].stock += 1;
this.setState(newCar);
```

It will make re-render since the newCar should be new object.
If it is not working, you can change the reference of array.
like this
`const newCar =  {...this.state.car};`

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you do this with `setState` this function can take in a function which receives the current state.

With the index you pass in to the `increment` function you can map over the `cars` in the state. If the `idx` of the item in the array is equal to the `index` you pass in the function you can update the stock.

```js
function increment(index) {
  this.setState((state) => {
    const newCars = state.cars.map((car, idx) => {
      if (index !== idx) return car;
      return {
        ...car,
        stock: car.stock + 1,
      };
    });
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: newCars,
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
function increment(index){
  let updateValue = this.state.cars;
  updateValue[0].stock++;
  this.setState({
   cars: [...updateValue]
  })
}
```

And yes each time you try to update value on state your component re-render